# Javascript working on jsfiddle but not wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Link of site: 
http://34.246.124.138/test/

The code works on JSfiddle but it's not working on my site. Is this a problem with my code or a theme I've used on my wordpress that is stopping it from working? I also have WP bakery installed within my site.

JS fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vwgeypfL/

The code-

```js
jQuery('#preference, #style').on('change', function(){
 var preference = jQuery('#preference');
  var style = jQuery('#style');
 if ( preference.prop('selectedIndex') > 0 && style.prop('selectedIndex') > 0 ) {
jQuery('.result.active').removeClass('active');
jQuery('.result').filter('[data-preference="' + preference.val() + '"][data-style="' + style.val() + '"]').addClass('active');
}
});
```

```css
.result {display:none;}
.result.active {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head><style>.result {display:none;}
.result.active {display:block;}</style>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<body></body>
<p>What is your astrology sign?</p>
<select id="preference">
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="aries">Aries</option>
    <option value="taurus">Taurus</option>
    <option value="gemini">Gemini</option>
    <option value="cancer">Cancer</option>
    <option value="leo">Leo</option>
    <option value="virgo">Virgo</option>
    <option value="libra">Libra</option>
    <option value="scorpio">Scorpio</option>
    <option value="sagittarius">Sagittarius</option>
    <option value="capricon">Capricon</option>
    <option value="aquarius">Aquarius</option>
    <option value="pisces">Pisces</option>
</select>


<select id="style">
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="sun">Sun</option>
    <option value="moon">Moon</option>
</select>


<div class="result" data-preference="aries" data-style="sun">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Cosmic Wind</h3>
<h6>“Creation, Preservation and Destruction, Breathe, Open your arms, fall all over again.” </h6>
</div>

<div class="result" data-preference="aries" data-style="moon">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Can I See It</h3>
<h6>“Sunlight’s Out Gonna Burn to the ground” </h6>
</div>

<div class="result" data-preference="taurus" data-style="sun">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>When I Told You I Loved You</h3>
<h6> “When I told you I loved you, I was for real."</h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="taurus" data-style="moon">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Into Me</h3>
<h6> “Intimacy, Sexually, Emotionally, Financially, Spiritually, get into me.”  </h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="gemini" data-style="sun">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Honey Dew</h3>
<h6> “Open Mind, Look I find something in the rain as it falls.”   </h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="gemini" data-style="moon">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Reminisce</h3>
<h6> “Sometimes I reminisce about you, things change every minute every season.” </h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="cancer" data-style="sun">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Can I See It</h3>
<h6> “Sunlight’s Out Gonna Burn to the ground” </h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="cancer" data-style="moon">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Different Planet</h3>
<h6> “Tell me how I feel so deep?” </h6>
</div>

<div class="result" data-preference="Leo" data-style="Sun">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Hit The Ceiling</h3>
<h6> “We ain’t got no limit, and we don’t let go”</h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="Leo" data-style="Moon">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>When I Told You I Loved You</h3>
<h6> “When I told you I loved you, I was for real."</h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="virgo" data-style="sun">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Anyway You Want To</h3>
<h6> “Anyway you want to we will go”  </h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="virgo" data-style="moon">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Never Before</h3>
<h6> “So what’s the move, I’m in the mood” </h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="Libra" data-style="sun">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>So Long</h3>
<h6> “You and me both know we needed to grow.“</h6>
</div>

<div class="result" data-preference="Libra" data-style="moon">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Honey Dew</h3>
<h6> “Open Mind, Look I find something in the rain as it falls.”   </h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="Scorpio" data-style="sun">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Sexy Please</h3>
<h6> “Can I be sexy please?”</h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="Scorpio" data-style="moon">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>So Long</h3>
<h6> “You and me both know we needed to grow.“</h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="sagittarius" data-style="sun">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Anyway You Want To</h3>
<h6> “Anyway you want to we will go”  </h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="sagittarius" data-style="moon">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>The Wave</h3>
<h6> “Everybody’s moving through the wave, let’s go.”</h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="capricorn" data-style="sun">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Into Me</h3>
<h6> “Intimacy, Sexually, Emotionally, Financially, Spiritually, get into me.”  </h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="capricorn" data-style="moon">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Western World</h3>
<h6>  “We should know what we’re breathing for, sooner we let it go, like a tree, we grow, we grow.” </h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="aquarius" data-style="sun">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>No Rules</h3>
<h6> “You tell me all of the things I gotta do, and I’ll let you know if I feel the same or if we’re through.”</h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="aquarius" data-style="moon">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Different Planet</h3>
<h6>“Tell me how I feel so deep?”  </h6></div>

<div class="result" data-preference="pisces" data-style="sun">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>The Wave</h3>
<h6> “Everybody’s moving through the wave, let’s go.”</h6>
</div>

<div class="result" data-preference="pisces" data-style="moon">
<p>Your Song Is</p>
<h3>Cosmic Wind</h3>
<h6>“Creation, Preservation and Destruction, Breathe, Open your arms, fall all over again.” </h6></div>
```

Comment: how did you add this file to wordpress ?

Comment: @G.aziz as text under WP Bakery

Answer (score 0):

Console is giving an error on line 309 of your index file.
[image]

Aaand the error is right here:

[image]

You have a duplicate of on "change" event subscribe there.

Comment: ah ok thanks so much!!! i'm still new to this. where can i find the index file on my wordpress?

Comment: It's actually the file where you put your script.